# connection between postgresql db and application(jsf+hibernate) running on cloudfoundry

Tags: database, postgresql, jsf, cloud-foundry

The application(JSF+hibernate) is been deployed using the vmc commands as on the cloudfoundry site. able to see the welcome page. postgreSQl service is binded with the application but the application is not able to connect with the database. 
And also viewed about the VCAP_SERVICES using java but dont know much about it rather how to create it.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Foundry uses auto-reconfiguration if you have one service (either MySQL or Postgres) bind to your application. That means you don't need to touch your code at all!

Please review the following article on our docs site:

http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/java/spring/spring.html#using-cloud-foundry-services-in-spring-applications

If you still have issues, go ahead and upload a war file of your app and we can take a look.

Comment: had gone through the link given above. created the context.xml file in META-INF as shown in the example

but when trying to deploy the application getting an error

Staging Application 'pothole1': OK
Starting Application 'pothole1': ..........................Error:
Application 'pothole1's state is undetermined, not enough information available

im confused how the context.xml would work. coz im using hibernate.cfg.xml to store the info required to connect to the DB.
if it is possible can u give me an example that uses context.xml file n is binded with a DB n is running.

Comment: Here is the github address for cloud foundry sample apps.

https://github.com/SpringSource/cloudfoundry-samples

Take a look at hello-spring-mysql and that should give you an idea.